# How can i getting first login from AD using C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I want to check some information like first login for user and i will force change password. I can getting current login but i don't know it is first login or not.

Comment: Take a look http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/36597525-af24-4be8-b4aa-c36a304e368a/force-users-to-change-password-when-first-login and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886713/force-local-user-to-change-password-at-next-login-with-c-sharp

Comment: i looked them, these are about force change password but indeed, i want to check other things like users' login is first login second login or third login

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [logonCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676845%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attribute of a user object to determine how many times a user has successfully authenticated against a particular domain controller.

Please note, however, that this attribute is not replicated in the domain, so each DC keeps its own value. To get an accurate number of logons for a particular user, you will have to read this value from all domain controllers and sum it up.

More information can be found on the MSDN page provided above.

PS. If you want to force password change on first logon, this is definitely NOT the way you want to go. Simply force the password change during the account creation.

Comment: i didn't know logonCount, i can try this attribute like

if (user.Properties["logonCount"] == 1)
{//
    user.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Value = 0;
}//

Comment: I still do not understand why you would like to force the user to change the account's password AFTER the user already logged in once. You should try to force the change BEFORE the first logon unless you have a very good business reason to do it this (less user-friendly) way...

Comment: No shouting included.:) Have fun! Just make sure you are having fun in a test environment.:)